# How to verify that it is not a duplicate employees ID before OR after adding new item?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

Using a lookup to populate multiple fields ( including employess ID ) on a form. 
How to verify that it is not a duplicate employees ID before OR after adding new item?

Comment: You can fire REST query with ID on list. If no item found in list that means ID will not getting duplicate in list.

Comment: Hello Dom, that is totally new to me, googled it but don't know where to start or apply it as you mentioned. Been going nuts trying o get this sort, would you be so kind to point the way? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee536168%28v=office.14%29.aspx (for devs) and http://adicodes.com/column-validations-and-list-validations-in-sharepoint-2010/

Answer (score 1):

On your list that holds the employee data, set the employee ID field to be unique, then you will be prevented from adding duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

Specific to your question, you could use an ItemAdding event receiver to validate that the employee ID you are adding does not exist.

However, for a field such as an EmployeeId you should reconsider using the default ID column associated with every list/library in SharePoint. It is like a primary key on SharePoint lists, and gets generated automatically.